# Does this nonlinear second order autonomous ode have an explicit solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-10\frac{dx}{dt}+24x=36x^2$$
have an explicit solution?

Here is what I tried: change variables $$y=xe^{-4t},s=e^{2t},$$
then the ode becomes
$$\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}=9y^2.$$
Consider $z=\frac{dy}{ds}$ as a function of $y$, we get $z\frac{dz}{dy}=9y^2$, its solution is $\frac{dy}{ds}=z=(6y^3+c_1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

But it seems unless $c_1=0$, we get an elliptic integral, which is implicit.

Could I set $c_1=0$? What will happen if I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: The two constants of integration are related to any boundary/initial conditions the problem may have. If you specify $c_1 = 0$ you are picking one of the infinitely many solutions you can find. Or, in other words, you are simplifying the kind of solution you get or fixing its value at a certain $t$.

Comment: Have you verified that the substitution you claimed is really workable to simplify the ODE efficiently you expected?

Comment: @doraemonpaul Yes, this is the simplest form I can get.

Answer (score 1):

The ODE is of the kind :
 $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+a\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$$
with, in the present case, $a=-10$ and $f(x)=36x^2-24x$

It is possible to reduce it to a first order ODE wit the change of function 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=u(x) \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=u\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$u\frac{du}{dx}=-au+f(x)$$
This is an Abel's differential equation of the second kind.

The change of function $u=\frac{1}{y}$ brings it to an Abel's equation of the first kind :
$$y'=ay^2-f(x)y^3$$
Most often, the solutions of the Abel ODEs are not known on closed form. This an old and not fully solved question. Only some particular cases are analytically solvable. If am afraid that it is not the case for your ODE. I didn't spent much time to look more deeply, so that is only my feeling, not an affirmation.